# Simple Monitor system (ping only)

Tags: linux, gratis, monitoring

What are the options for a simple monitoring system:

- Operating System to install on: Linux
- Only need to ping device.
- Send alerts if devices are not responding to ping.
- Simple to add devices - such as adding IP address in a text file with a description.
- Alerts to be sent on email when hosts are not responding.
- Will be monitoring 25-75 devices.
- Don't need any web interface or anything else than ping, but if it has such, it is not a problem.
- A script scheduled with Cron would be ok. But the best would be something with a bit of intelligence such as notify when host is back up after a down.
- Free.

**Note**: A script would be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used to use the following script, it does everything you asked for. You just need to add a cronjob entry so that it gets executed regularly:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Simple SHELL script for Linux and UNIX system monitoring with
# ping command
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2006 nixCraft project <http://www.cyberciti.biz/fb/>
# This script is licensed under GNU GPL version 2.0 or above
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This script is part of nixCraft shell script collection (NSSC)
# Visit http://bash.cyberciti.biz/ for more information.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Setup email ID below
# See URL for more info:
# http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/simple-linux-and-unix-system-monitoring-with-ping-command-and-scripts.html
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# add ip / hostname separated by while space
HOSTS='cat server_list.txt'

# no ping request
COUNT=1

# email report when
SUBJECT="Ping failed"
EMAILID="test@domain.com"
for myHost in $HOSTS
do
  count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
  if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
    # 100% failed
    echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" $EMAILID
  fi
done
```

Comment: I was going to write one, but it seems like you beat me!  +1